# Force an application to use a specific connection

Tags: linux, networking, wlan, networkmanager

So my Mint 17 has 2 connections (wired and wireless) when both connected by default the wired is used, what I want to do is keep wireless for file download and  general Internet usage, and use the Wired connection for playin online game (steam game)

So I was wondering if that is doable

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways you can do it.

One clean way is to use separate network namespaces, using `ip netns`. Put your game and wired interface into one network namespace and leave everything else in the default one. The trouble is that none of the tooling and network configuration user interfaces will help you with this. For example you'd probably end up making a script to set up the alternate namespace including running a DHCP client inside it by invoking it directly (i.e. not by configuring it in `/etc/network/interfaces`).

Another way is to use a combination of `iptables` and policy routing (`ip rule`) to catch the traffic that comes from your game (perhaps identified by running as a separate user ID) and route it using an alternate routing table where the default route points to your wired interface.

Answer (score 0):

It is doable with traffic control [tc](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Traffic-Control-HOWTO/index.html) and `iptables ... -m owner --uid-owner user1 -j MARK --set-mark number`. And run application as user1.

It is possible to redirect specific packets to different network interfaces. You could also shape traffic to use single wired connection and use different applications with different speed limits.